# Potential XSS Vulnerability

Tags: bug, status-norepro, xss

I just thought I'd let everyone know that I found a bug in the comments (and possibly questions as well). I went to post a comment in webmasters and I put < noscript > in it and instead of it just showing the tag, it parsed it as actual HTML. I am not sure if this can lead to XSS but I am not leaving that to doubt. Please fix this.

Comment: AFAIK this is by design and *very* stringently whitelisted. Can you show an actual XSS attack using this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this for comments. Also, I have a hard time believing that somebody could abuse the `<noscript>` tag for cross-site *scripting*.

Comment: <noscript>Hello, world</noscript> I can't reproduce this. I tried it on Webmasters.SE too, nothing.

Comment: This is not a bug and it does not need to be fixed. There are many tags which are white listed and are not escaped.

Comment: I don't believe you < noscript >.  Darn, I was wrong.

Comment: Nope, [not a single one, did my best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment424306_81709).

Comment: Was it `< noscript >` or `<noscript>`?

Comment: what is a XSS attack.?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: XSS means [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: +1 thanx. I used t work with android mobile platform, so never faced such a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's *no* HTML allowed in comments. This includes all tags and (sadly) character references.

Since you wrote

> I found a bug in the comments (and possibly questions as well).

and you used the `<noscript>` tag in [your latest answer on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/34756), I suppose you meant *answers* (not comments), you refer to the line

```
<noscript>Text goes here</noscript>
```

and you inspected the HTML code in the developer tools (or whatever it's called in your browser).

Indeed, Chrome shows the following:

```
<pre>
  <code><noscript>Text goes here</noscript>
  </code>
</pre>
```

However, the `<noscript>` tag is black, meaning that's it's not an actual HTML tag (which are purple). Indeed, right-clicking the `<pre>` tag and choosing **Edit as HTML** reveals that the actual source code reads the following:

```
<pre><code>&lt;noscript&gt;Text goes here&lt;/noscript&gt;
</code></pre>
```